# Dynamic HTML form inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to do simple dynamic forms input for files uploading

```
$('.add_field_button').click(function(e){   
    $('.input_fields_wrap').append('<input type="file" class="form" name="fileField" />');       
});
```

i just tested simple this script is working everyting fine, but my html template using two inputs for file uploading

```
<input type="text" class="form" name="textfield" /> this showing only selected file
<input type="file" class="form" name="fileField" /> this showing only select button
```

and when i need to apppend all this two inputs

```
$('.input_fields_wrap').append('<input type="text" class="form" name="textfield" /><input type="file" class="form" name="fileField" />');
```

i append like this, is looking good, but when i'm browse file ant try to select he not selecting for appended forms just showing blank text input.

Comment: Perhaps they are cluttered together by the size of the .input_fields_wrap element, inspect with your dev toolbar and increase the parent element size. Perhaps when you see all buttons you will be able to click them in order to upload properly.
Option 2: Consider having those inputs always there, just hidden so you can only show() them with jQuery.

Comment: .input_fields_wrap is just container, dont have any css rules, and what size increase? When i press button input was appending good, but when i try to select its showing blank. How it look like [link](http://postimg.org/image/jyzwt1b5p/)

Comment: there is definitely some CSS applied to these inputs as no browser defaults them to green. Look into removing ALL CSS from the page and see if this fixes the problem. If, so, there is a rule there that breaks things. Othewise, post here the full code that can let someone reproduce the problem in order to look into it